# Installing Xcode 4.1 Issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, app-store

I am installing Xcode 4.1. I downloaded it from the App Store (on Lion) and now it's been more than an hour "Updating Files". When I click Xcode however, Xcode opens up in 4.1. What is this? Is this normal? Can I just force quit Xcode? Did it upgrade but just hang?

Thank you

Comment: I'm seeing this too.  I'm still waiting for spotlight indexing to complete from the Lion update too, perhaps the installer is blocking on access to the index in order to register developer docs? *shrug*

Comment: Also, some reports suggest an issue with Xcode Installer asking to quit iTunes, even if it isn't running.  You may need to kill the iTunesHelper process.  (http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2011/Jul/msg00253.html)  This didn't fix mine though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since at the end of the process I was still able to fire up Xcode 4.1, I just quit the installer and restarted it. It took 30 minutes or so and it was completed. Everything works now.